# Redirecting audio signals coming from a JACK audio connection kit client to MATLAB/Simulink in linux

Tags: matlab, audio, simulink

## Description of my scenario

My main computer is connected through network as a **JACK** client to an embedded board working as master with a loopback connection via I2S to another board that acts as a filter. So far I've been able to play some audio using applications like [mpv](https://mpv.io/manual/stable/#audio) and get the filtered audio back into my computer and redirect it to other **JACK** compatible applications using [qjackctl](https://qjackctl.sourceforge.io/).

Here's a diagram of the pipeline I'm trying to implement
[image: Target signal analysis pipeline]

I want to somehow direct that incoming filtered audio signal into Simulink's [Audio Device Reader block](https://www.mathworks.com/help/audio/ref/audiodevicereader.html) so I can do some analysis in real time.

## What I've tried

I've looked into the `Audio Device Reader` block settings and I haven't found anything **JACK** related in the *Device* tab, the only options I have available are:

- hw:0,0
- hw:0,3
- hw:0,7
- default
- sysdefault

and when I try to pick one of those (for example hw:0,0) while using the [alsa_in and alsa_out](https://man.archlinux.org/man/extra/jack-example-tools/alsa_in.1.en) utilities to be able to redirect the audio to another **JACK** compatible application, Simulink throws an error saying it cannot open the device.

I was wondering if it was possible to somehow funnel an audio signal from a **JACK** compatible application into one of these available devices so MATLAB can pick it up.

I'm open to any ideas and suggestions on how to accomplish this, even if I have to do some programming myself.